# How can I call a method on a form from a method called from an external class from a backgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, class, backgroundworker, delegates

How can I call a method on a form from a method called from an external class from a backgroundWorker? I believe that delegates are somehow the answer to this question, but after spending time reading, I still am confused by this problem.

This is in Visual Studio 2008, the **backgroundWorker** is run from the form and calls **ExternalClass.Method**. The form is in *namespace* **ProgramName** and the **ExternalClass** is *using* **ProgramName**. When i declare *public delegate* **MyDelegate** in the *namespace* **ProgramName** in the file of my windows.form I can create an instance of **MyDelegate** and call it in a method of my form (but this does not help me), but if I try to create an instance of **MyDelegate** and call it from a method of my external class I cannot access the method of the windows.form, even though it is public.

thanks

yes, I want to pass progress reports (int percent, string status) back from **ExternalClass.Method**. Can you explain a bit more about that CSharpAtl (or anyone)?

Comment: Do you want the external class to be able to signal the calling class something?  If so you can put an event on the background worker class that the calling class subscribes to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your question (afaik) is not just about the backgroundwiorker but just as much about how to break a circular reference between classes. This is a standard problem with a standard solution.

You can pass a delegate (referring to a Form-method) around just as any object so also to a Backgroundworker. And the Bgw can pass it to the external method. A delegate includes a reference to the object (in this case the Form).

Note that since you are on another thread you will need to use Control.Invoke inside the delegate, or use the Bgw ReportProgress event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void ReportProgresshandler(int percent, string state)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent);  // also does the Invoke
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = new ExampleClass();
        ex.Dowork(ReportProgresshandler);    
    }
}
```

and something like

```
class ExampleClass
{
    delegate void ReportDelegate(int percent, string status);

    public void Dowork(ReportDelegate report)
    {
        report(0, "starting");
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to help Clarify, you'll need to use the *Form*'s Invoke() method, not Delegate.Invoke().

Comment: Yoooder: good point, absolutely. I sidestepped it using ReportProgress.

Answer (score 2):

Please do yourself a favor and read up on the [BackgroundWorker Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8dcext2.aspx), especially "[How to: Implement a Form That Uses a Background Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc.aspx)".

Other resources:

- [Windows Client Development Portal](http://windowsclient.net/)
- [Using the BackgroundWorker Control](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=12392) (video)
- [Windows Forms Videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to realize is that you actually have two levels of synchronization going on here: between the Form and the BackgroundWorker, and between the BackgroundWorker and the ExternalClass object.

The Form is asynchronously invoking `BackgroundWorker.DoWork()`, which is running in another thread.  Any updates to the Form should come through `Form.Invoke()` (which fires an arbitrary delegate in the Form's thread) or, better yet, through the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event (which fires a specific event in the Form's thread).

So what you want to do is *proxy* the status updates from the ExternalClass method back to the BackgroundWorker, which will in turn push them on to the Form.  One way I've done this in the past is to use a callback delegate:

```
public delegate void ProgressCallback(double percentCompleted, string status);
```

And have my expensive worker method take the callback as an argument:

```
public void ExpensiveMethod(ProgressCallback callback) {
    while(doingThings) {
        if(callback != null) callback(percentDone, statusString);
    }
}
```

Then in your BackgroundWorker class, define a method that matches your callback delegate, and have it call `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` to trigger the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event, which can in turn update your Form's state.

Update: this is basically the same as the solution Henk Holterman suggested in his new edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the trouble is. And also you can use a delegate, but don't need one.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class ExampleForm : Form
{

    public ExampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(this);
    }

    void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ExampleForm f = e.Argument as ExampleForm;
        f.Hello();
    }

    private void Hello()
    {

    }

}
```